# No WhatsApp notification on Xperia S after updating to JellyBean

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have Xperia S running Android ICS, and the notifications of a new message of WhatsApp appeared in the top notification panel showing an icon of WhatsApp. I received an update to JellyBean and after that, I'm not seeing the notification icon when a new message is received.

If the volume is high, all I can hear is the new message tone, but there is absolutely no notification showing the new message received.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Found the solution myself. In Settings>Apps>Whatsapp. There is a check box right below the Icon which says "Show notifications" Check it and it is solved.

Comment: If you found an answer to your own problem, please post it as an answer and accept it, so that the others can also get benefited from it.

Answer (score 1):

From [OP's self-comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54829/no-whatsapp-notification-in-the-pulldown-menu-in-xperia-s#comment73555_54829),

> In Settings>Apps>Whatsapp. There is a check box right below the Icon which says "Show notifications" Check it and it is solved.